# How can select multiple marker of google map

Tags: javascript, google-maps

I am using google map apis in my application. I have to perform some operation on selecting the multiple markers. Is there any way that  i can use to select multiple markers pressing ctrl key and clicking the marker.
enter code here

```
var selectedMarker=[];
 google.maps.event.addListener(marker, 'click', function (event) {
   if (event.ctrlKey) {
      selectedMarker.push(marker);
      alert("Hi aditya");
    }
});
```

I found this solution from stackoverflow, but it is not working for me.
Please help. Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 0):

Did you add `google.maps.event.addDomListener(window, 'load', initialize);`

[DOM Events](https://developers.google.com/maps/documentation/javascript/events#DomEvents)